# Удалить записи, существующие в единственном числе

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE test(
 item_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test(item_id, parent_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 2);
```

Необходимо выбрать все item_id, для которых parent_id = <значение> и которые не существуют c другими значениями parent_id. (в примере это item_id = 3 для parent_id = 2 и item_id = 1 для parent_id = 1)

```
SELECT s.item_id from test s WHERE s.parent_id = 2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM test t WHERE t.parent_id <> 2 AND t.item_id = s.item_id);
```

запрос в лоб выглядит крайне неоптимальным)
По логике вещей при группировке по item_id надо выбрать всё, у кого parent_id = <значение> и COUNT = 1, но как написать хз)

Comment: `SELECT s.item_id from test s
     GROUP BY s.item_id
    HAVING max(parent_id)=2 and min(parent_id)=2`  Но я сомневаюсь, что это оптимальнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> выбрать все item_id, для которых parent_id = <значение> и которые не существуют c другими значениями parent_id

```
SELECT item_id
FROM `table`
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING MIN(parent_id) = MAX(parent_id)
```

Выберутся `item_id` с единственным (даже если таких записей несколько несколько) одним и тем же `parent_id`, если он не NULL. Если нужны и NULL - заменить равенство на null-safe compare `<=>`.

Наличие индекса `(item_id, parent_id)` весьма желательно.

PS. Альтернативные варианты - с коррелированным подзапросом и с 2 копиями,- вряд ли будут производительнее...

Comment: спасибо, расскажите мне, что за лайфхак с мин(...) = макс(...) ? получается мы группируем по итем_ид, среди этих подгрупп мы ищем минимальное и максимальное значение парент_ид и равенство сработает только в том случае, когда это один элемент, я правильно понял?

Comment: @goldstar_labs Ну да... это же очевидно.